# mod_deflate logging

Tags: apache, logging

I've got the following in my Includes directory on an Apache2.2 setup but it is not logging

```
    AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html text/plain php application/x-httpd-php application/json
    #Highest 9 - Lowest 1                                                                
    DeflateCompressionLevel 9

   #Optional
   #Skip browsers with known problems
   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4 gzip-only-text/html
   BrowserMatch ^Mozilla/4\.0[678] no-gzip
   BrowserMatch \bMSIE !no-gzip !gzip-only-text/html

   #Optional
   #Logging
   DeflateFilterNote ratio
   LogFormat '"%r" %b (%{ratio}n) "%{User-agent}i"' deflate
   CustomLog /usr/vhosts/example.com/logs/deflate_log deflate
```

However, I am getting no logging.  Permissions on the log file are root:wheel -rw-r--r--

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

A guess here but you mentioned Apache includes which makes me thing you have a separate files for your site or multiple vhosts decelerations, therefore ensure that you are specifying which logformat to use, for example:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
...

ServerAdmin support@danols.com
ServerName webdesign.danols.com
ServerAlias www.webdesign.danols.com new.webdesign.danols.com

#LogLevel info
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/webdesign.danols.com-errors.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/webdesign.danols.com-vhost_combined_deflate-access.log vhost_combined_deflate

...
    </VirtualHost>
```

Then verify that the site is actually being compressed using - http://www.whatsmyip.org/http-compression-test/ and now your logs should show look like this (notice the compressions stat at the end of requests):

```
webdesign.danols.com:443 72.38.184.18 - - [28/Mar/2013:09:52:19 -0400] "GET /static/template/images/icons/dark/ohloh-w32-h32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 3076 "https://webdesign.danols.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31" "2595/2867 (90%)"
webdesign.danols.com:443 72.38.184.18 - - [28/Mar/2013:09:52:19 -0400] "GET /static/template/images/icons/dark/designquote-w32-h32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2564 "https://webdesign.danols.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31" "2079/2360 (88%)"
webdesign.danols.com:443 72.38.184.18 - - [28/Mar/2013:09:52:19 -0400] "GET /static/template/images/bg_direction_nav.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2612 "https://webdesign.danols.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31" "2137/2427 (88%)"
webdesign.danols.com:443 72.38.184.18 - - [28/Mar/2013:09:52:19 -0400] "GET /static/template/images/icons/dark/designgigs-w32-h32.png HTTP/1.1" 200 2372 "https://webdesign.danols.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.31 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/26.0.1410.43 Safari/537.31" "1887/2171 (86%)"
```